# Should I create separate MySQL indexes for url_title vs url_title, url_description, url_keywords?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, full-text-search, database-administration

Using MySQL 5.7, I have a table of urls containing url_title, url_description, url_keywords

Sometimes I just need to look in url_title, but sometimes look for something in all columns.

Is it better to just create one index containing all 3 columns or create a separate index for url_title alone and another index containing all 3 columns ?

e.g Will it search for url_title slower in the 3 columns index vs single column ?

Or can MySQL only search/read in given column even if index would contain 3 columns ?

**Later edit:** this is a sample query but I do have other less important variations:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  urls
    WHERE  match(url_title, url_description,
                 url_keywords, url_paragraphs)
           against('red boots' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    LIMIT  500
```

Comment: Index by `(a,b)` improves the queries with the conditions by `a` and by `a AND b` columns (index seek is used) and slightly improves the queries with the conditions by `b` (index scan is used, i.e. an index is used like compact table version). Of course the improvement strength and presence depends on the data statistic.

Comment: Show us the relevant queries.  The only realistic way to decide on optimal index(es) is to look at the important queries.

Comment: @RickJames I added a sample query

Comment: Stating fulltext _in_ the body of the Question would have gotten to the desired Answer faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: You didn't mention in your original post that you were talking about fulltext indexes, not conventional B-tree indexes.

Fulltext indexes are a different type. You must specify ALL the columns of the fulltext index in your `MATCH()` clause. No fewer, and no more, and they must be in the same order as they appear in the index definition.

If you want to do a fulltext search only on a single column sometimes, then you will have to create another fulltext with that single column.

Below is my original answer, that I wrote before you clarified that you were using a fulltext index. Perhaps it will help someone else.

---

MySQL can use the index if the column(s) you search are the leftmost column(s) of that index. It can use a subset of the columns of a multi-column index.

For example, given an index on `(a, b, c)`, the following query uses all three columns:

```
SELECT ... WHERE a = ? AND b = ? AND c = ?
```

The following query uses the first column `a` of the index, because it's the leftmost column.

```
SELECT ... WHERE a = ?
```

The following query uses the first two columns of the index, because they're consecutive and the leftmost subset of columns.

```
SELECT ... WHERE a = ? AND b = ?
```

The following query uses only the first column `a` of the index, because the conditions don't match consecutive columns of the index. It will use the index to narrow down the search to rows matching the `a` condition, but then it will have to examine each of those rows to evaluate the `c` condition, even though `c` is part of the same index.

```
SELECT ... WHERE a = ? AND c = ?
```

MySQL has an optimization called [index condition pushdown](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html) which does a short-cut for this. It delegates to the storage engine to evaluate the `c` condition, knowing that `c` is part of the index. So it still counts as examining the row, but it make the row read a little bit less costly.

The following query cannot use the index at all, because the conditions are not on leftmost columns of that index.

```
SELECT ... WHERE b = ? AND c = ?
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I added a sample query to my question, maybe it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The guidelines for `FULLTEXT` indexes and `MATCH...AGAINST` are different than for `INDEX`.  For this:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  urls
    WHERE  match(url_title, url_description,
                 url_keywords, url_paragraphs)
           against('red boots' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    LIMIT  500
```

(and assuming `ENGINE=InnoDB`), you need a `FULLTEXT` index with all 4 columns in it.

```
FULLTEXT(url_title, url_description,
         url_keywords, url_paragraphs)
```

If you might also be searching, say, just `url_title` in another query, then you would also need `FULLTEXT(url_title)`.  (Etc)

See if either of these would be 'better' for your application:

```
           against('+red +boots' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
           against('red boots')
```